# ZedGraph Chart - Zooming data to fit the entire chart area?

Tags: c#, winforms, zedgraph

[image: Image describing issue]

I want the data (X axis) to always span the entire graph pane. Is there a property or method that does this?

Here are some properties I have set for the X axis:

```
myPane.XAxis.Title.IsVisible = false;
myPane.XAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.DateAsOrdinal;
myPane.XAxis.MajorGrid.Color = Color.Black;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION:**

```
private PointPairList ppl;
...
GraphPane myPane = zedChartControl.GraphPane;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = true;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinAuto = true;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 1;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = Convert.ToDouble(ppl.Count);
```

Local variable `ppl` is a `PointPairList (double x, double y)` comprised of `XDate` as X and values as Y.

Setting `XAxis.Scale.Min = 1;` sets the beginning X value to `ppl[0]`

Settings `XAxis.Scale.Max = Convert.ToDouble(ppl.Count);` sets the end value to the last ppl item (i.e. ppl[34])

The entire span of the X axis would now be 1-34.

Here is the result using a different chart:

[image: Issue resolved]

Sometimes the answer is a lot simpler than expected.

Comment: Why don't you post a more complete solution as the answer? It will be helpful for people in the future who run into this issue as well.

Comment: Please see Grace subtitle at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5431/A-flexible-charting-library-for-NET